# Importing subject fields from a text file (openSSL x509)?

Tags: command-line, import, scripting, openssl, x509certificate

Is it possible to import the `-subj` from a text file openSSL?

Hi I'm trying to create a self signed certificate for a school project and I need to import the `-subj` fields from a .txt file.

What I have now is:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout  key.key -out key.csr -subj "/C=US/ST=NY/L=NY/O=HW/CN=NAME"
```

Is it possible to import the file with a built in function using only one line of code?

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout  key.key -out key.csr -subj "filename.txt"
```

If not how should I approach this issue? I'm using simple batch files to create certificates

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`` openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout  key.key -out key.csr -subj `cat filename.txt` ``